# Obtener timeline de un usuario de Twitter con tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

Tengo que sacar el `timeline` de mi perfil de twitter y el de un usuario que nosotros queramos con [tweepy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy/3.5.0) y sacar por pantalla la **fecha** ,el **autor** y el **text**o.

Tengo el siguiente código, pero me muestra solo el texto de mi timeline:

```
import tweepy

#Credenciales de desarrollador que se obtienen en https://apps.twitter.com/
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

opcion = int(input("\nMENU\n\t"+
           "1.Mostrar mi TimeLine\n"+"Que quieres hacer: "));

while(opcion !=7):
    if(opcion == 1):
         for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(20):
                 print status.text+'\n'
         break;
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que me saque la fecha y el autor?

¿Y cómo puedo hacer lo mismo pero con otro usuario que quiera? Que nos pida el nombre de un usuario y saque los datos de él.

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar un fragmento de código que permita reproducir tu problema? Intenta realizar un [mcve]

Comment: import tweepy
Aqui deberias sacar tu propias keys,si te doi las mias entras en mi twitter jeje
CONSUMER_KEY = ''"
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''"
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

opcion = int(input("\nMENU\n\t"+
     "1.Mostrar mi TimeLine\n"+"Que quieres hacer: "));

while(opcion !=7):
 if(opcion == 1):
   for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(20):
           print status.text+'\n'
   break;

Comment: Para agregarlo, encontrarás el enlace [edit] debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: Deje arriba un enlace a mega con el codigo,tendras que usar https://apps.twitter.com/ para generar tu key,las mias no puedo darte y tendras que instalar tweepy para que funcione

Comment: Fer he añadido el código del enlace por esta vez pero evita siempre que sea posible usar enlaces externos. Formatear adecuadamente el código es tan fácil como seleccionarlo y pulsar Ctrl + k o pulsar el botón `{}` en el editor. Más imformación en [Ayuda de edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el timeline de un usuario solo tienes que especificar su `screen_name`  pasandolo como  parámetro a `api.user_timeline()`. Puedes ver la lista de parámetros y sus significados en la [documetación de la API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Para obtener la fecha, el autor y el texto simplemente accedes al atributo que desees, en tu caso:

- `status.created_at` retorna la fecha y hora en tipo [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html).
- `status.author.screen_name` retorna un string con el nombre (screen_name) del tweet. Puedes obtener mucha más información sobre el autor, como la id, lenguaje, localización, imagen de perfil, seguidores, etc. Puedes hacer `print(status.author)` para ver la información retornada.
- `status.text`: retorna un string con el texto en si del tweet

Te dejo un ejemplo  básico basado en tu código para que veas el funcionamiento:

**Para Python 3.x:**

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = '*****'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '******'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '******'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '******'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


def get_stuff(nombre=None):
    stuff = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name = nombre, include_rts = True)
    return stuff

def get_tweets(stuff, n):
    for status in stuff.items(n):
        print(status.created_at, status.author.screen_name, status.text)

menu = '''
MENU
\t1.Mostrar mi TimeLine
\t2.Mostrar Timeline de otro usuario
\t3.Salir

Que quieres hacer: '''


opcion = 0
while not opcion == '3':

    opcion = input(menu)

    if opcion == '1':
        n = int(input('Cuantos tweets desea obtener: '))
        stuff = get_stuff()
        get_tweets(stuff, n)

    elif opcion == '2':
        nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre del usuario: ')
        n = int(input('Cuantos tweets desea obtener: '))
        stuff = get_stuff(nombre)
        get_tweets(stuff, n)

    else:
        print('Opción no válida')
```

**Para Python 2.X:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = 'Ifdw98rDoyw8K9KCnQTVvgvNt'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'hif0sSJ4nHdVBm7R7ldQlEPiUEw6WTgqgvSvpSBo0BPCEbj8Yf'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '564045096-WCVSX3KicrOw0f1uu3J4yAwa9dnYO7S8O9ZIpv3c'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'D4wLAiu4Wa3qwEihV6RqO8SCZ5apGKN9NFKir4Cx264EO'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


def get_stuff(nombre=None):
    stuff = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name = nombre, include_rts = True)
    return stuff

def get_tweets(stuff, n):
    for status in stuff.items(n):
        print '{0} {1} {2}'.format(
            status.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
            status.author.screen_name.encode('utf8'),
            status.text.encode('utf8')
            )

menu = '''
MENU
\t1.Mostrar mi TimeLine
\t2.Mostrar Timeline de otro usuario
\t3.Salir

Que quieres hacer: '''


opcion = ''
while not opcion == '3':

    opcion = raw_input(menu)

    if opcion == '1':
        n = input('Cuantos tweets desea obtener: ')
        stuff = get_stuff()
        get_tweets(stuff, n)

    elif opcion == '2':
        nombre = raw_input('Ingrese el nombre del usuario: ')
        n = input('Cuantos tweets desea obtener: ')
        stuff = get_stuff(nombre)
        get_tweets(stuff, n)

    else:
        print('Opción no válida')
```

Ejemplo usando la opcion 2 para obtener los 5 tweets del twitter de StackOverflow:

```
MENU
    1.Mostrar mi TimeLine
    2.Mostrar Timeline de otro usuario
    3.Salir

Que quieres hacer: 2
Ingrese el nombre del usuario: StackOverflow
Cuantos tweets desea obtener: 5
2016-12-06 23:29:57 StackOverflow RT @spolsky: Anil Dash is the New CEO at Fog Creek Software https://t.co/IVnVhRc94t https://t.co/5GkdcaLR0S
2016-12-06 15:45:43 StackOverflow @anildash @FogCreek https://t.co/z1LInUtGK7
2016-12-06 14:46:13 StackOverflow Congratulations to our friends at @FogCreek for launching #Gomix today, and to @anildash for his new role: https://t.co/CgSY6wXL3S
2016-12-05 23:06:05 StackOverflow RT @Nick_Craver: So does anyone else countdown in seconds, or is that just us? https://t.co/JNuIppNUvD https://t.co/j2VHnKTrTh
2016-12-05 23:05:42 StackOverflow RT @sklivvz: Hey, I got interviewed by JUG.ru about Stack Overflow. And there's a picture of a rocket. https://t.co/RDRU8kK2kh
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo otra versión que procesa la información que quieres con python 2.X:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy
from os import environ
CONSUMER_SECRET = environ["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
ACCESS_TOKEN = environ["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = environ['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

def print_tweet(status):
    print """
--------------------------------------------
Por: {0}
- {1}
Fecha: {2}
""".format(status.author.screen_name,
            status.text.encode('utf8'),
            status.created_at.strftime("%d/%b/%Y"))

opcion = ""
while(opcion !=7):
    opcion = int(input("""\nMENU\n
        1. Mostrar mi TimeLine
        2. Timeline de un usuario especifico
        7. Salir
        Que quieres hacer : """));
    if(opcion == 1):
        for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(2):
            print_tweet(status)
    elif(opcion == 2):
        screen_name = str(raw_input("nombre de usuario: "))
        for status in api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name):
            print_tweet(status)
```

Ignora la parte en la que ingreso las keys desde las variables de entorno, agregue el "encode(utf8)" para que pueda mostrar correctamente todo los tweets.

Resultado:

```
MENU

        1. Mostrar mi TimeLine
        2. Timeline de un usuario especifico
        7. Salir
        Que quieres hacer : 1

--------------------------------------------
Por: UrielAero
- RT @pragdave: Emailing by students notes on their grades. Programming by pipeline. Transformative!

#myelixirstatus https://t.co/iGR5FO6qsl
Fecha: 08/Dec/2016


--------------------------------------------
Por: UrielAero
- RT @plataformatec: This week we are releasing a beta with all chapters of our free Ecto 2.0 ebook.
Grab your copy |&gt; https://t.co/UUw5YhJk…
Fecha: 07/Dec/2016


MENU

        1. Mostrar mi TimeLine
        2. Timeline de un usuario especifico
        7. Salir
        Que quieres hacer :
```